# Instagram PHP API Invalid Login Url and Scopes Request

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm using the following PHP library for Instagram API:

```
https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API
```

My web PHP application generates successfully the following Login Url to Instagram:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=ec3a193ca6ad40b2aec8370f1fb53b86&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdashboard.php&scope=basic+relationships+likes+comments&response_type=code
```

When I'm logging-in, I see only this scope:

```
Access your basic information - Includes photos, friend lists & profile info
```

And then, when I try to modify a relationship (follow a user), I see the following error:

```
[error_type] => OAuthPermissionsException
[code] => 400
[error_message] => This request requires scope=relationships, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=relationships to be granted write permissions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instagram now requires that you request special permission from them in order to POST or DELETE follows, likes and comments. So you will not be able to follow a user with the API until Instagram grants you these permissions.

Here is where you request access: https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

FYI, here are guidelines from Instagram about requesting these permissions: "The ability to POST and DELETE likes, follows and comments is restricted to applications that offer business services and not consumer facing apps."